# does new version libstdc++ compatible with older version

Tags: gcc, compatibility, libstdc++

my os default gcc version is 4.8.5, I compiled a program use gcc-11, so this program cannot be run for a older libstdc++.so.6, can I use libstdc++.so.6 from gcc-11 substitute older one gloabally(means as an default one at system wide)? after substitute, can other program compiled with gcc-4.8.5 also works well without any problem?

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html, we can see libstdc++.so.6.0.17 is forward compatible with libstdc++.so.6.0.18 - libstdc++.so.6.0.31 so far, but notice some compile flags for build gcc itself may cause forward incompatible if you build gcc youself.

Comment: another solution may link gcc c++ runtime statically use -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc